# Array method to LinkedList method conversion

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, linked-list

I am having trouble rewriting a Array List loop method to work with a LinkedList.

Here is what I got so far:

```
public static int[] stutter(LinkedList<Integer> noStutter) {
            int[] result = new int[5 * 2];

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                result[2 * i] = noStutter[i];
                result[2 * i + 1] = noStutter[i];
            }
            System.out.println("Stutter: " + Arrays.toString(result));
            return result;

        }
```

This is the original Array list

```
public static int[] stutter(int[] noStutter) {
        int[] result = new int[noStutter.length * 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < noStutter.length; i++) {
            result[2 * i] = noStutter[i];
            result[2 * i + 1] = noStutter[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Stutter: " + Arrays.toString(result));
        return result;
```

The for loop is the big problem. I can't seem to get an index to work properly.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: use `get(i)` method to access value.

Comment: No, **don't use `get(i)` on a `LinkedList`**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a `LinkedList`, **do not access by index**. That is **slow**.

Instead, use an `Iterator`.

```
Iterator<Integer> iter = list.iterator();
for (int i = 0; iter.hasNext(); i+=2) {
    result[2*i] = iter.next();
    result[2*i + 1] = result[2*i]; // don't call next twice...
}
```

You will find `Iterator` being discussed in *any* Java book or tutorial. They are one of the most central concepts / APIs in Java.

Comment: `result [2 * i] = iter.next();` Throws a NullPointerException

Comment: Then you either did not initialize `iter`, or your *list* maybe contains `null` values (which cannot be converted to `int`). You'll need to debug this yourself; I don't have your full code (plus, you need to learn debugging)

Comment: its actually for result. How else would I initialize result other then "= null"

Comment: how about `new int[list.size() * 2]`?